# Anchored excludes with find or fd

Tags: find, fd

Let's say I want to find all files in a directory (recursively), but omit those e.g. in `.git` and `node_modules` subdirectories. I can do:

```
$ fd -uut f -E .git -E node_modules
```

But that will, for example, exclude `./some/dir/node_modules/*` or some such.

In this case that's probably okay, but I don't want to consider every time I need to find something whether non-anchored search will do. Not to mention that in some cases it won't.

How do I exclude `./dir`, but not `./**/dir`?

Comment: `-E /.git` seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To differentiate amongst the two cases, make use of the `-path` predicate:

```
$ find . -path ./a -prune -o -type f -print
```